# I am facing issue with sending status code,its always send 500,even though I am sending 204 in jax-rs webservices

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

I am using jersey framework to develop RESTful web service. I am throwing various HTTP status codes with response using following code:

```
public class WebException extends Exception implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Response.Status status = Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST;

    public WebException() {
        super();
    }


    public WebException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

    public WebException(String msg, Exception e) {
        super(msg, e);
    }

    public WebException(String msg, Response.Status status) {
        super(msg);
        this.status = status;
    }

    public WebException(String msg, Exception e, Response.Status status) {
        super(msg, e);
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Response.Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}

@Provider
public class WebApplicationExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<WebException> 
{
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(WebException exception) 
    {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {

            json.put("message", exception.getMessage());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------"+exception.getStatus());
        return Response.status(exception.getStatus()).entity(json.toString()).build();
    }
}

@GET
    @Path("/get-employee-details")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getEmplyeeDetails(@QueryParam("id") int employeeId) throws WebException   {
        if (true) {
            throw new WebException(""
                    + "No data found",Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return Response.ok("done", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

    }
```

I am using jersey framework to develop RESTful web service. I am throwing various HTTP status codes with response using following code:

Comment: HTTP 500 indicates a server error.  i.e.  Your code is throwing an exception which is being caught by the container which is in turn responding to clients with the HTTP 500.  Perhaps if you would provide your error log it would shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: stack trace from server please.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response,I want to override the status code,could you please guide me how I can oveeride. Please find details exception what I am getting :Jul 05, 2016 5:39:28 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
com.poc.exception.WebException: No data found
 at com.poc.controller.MainController.getEmplyeeDetails(MainController.java:40)

Comment: It seems type is not matching when you are passing Status.NOT_FOUND to match this parameter Response.Status status. What is Status class by the way ?

Comment: @user2424101 Are you adding WebApplicationExceptionHandler as a class in your Application.getClasses() implementation?  Please consider renaming the WebException class you define to reduce possible confusion.